# Replacing Turkish characters with English characters

Tags: macros, sas, enterprise-guide

I have a table which has 120 columns and some of them is including Turkish characters (for example "ç","ğ","ı","ö"). So i want to replace this Turkish characters with English characters (for example "c","g","i","o"). When i use "TRANWRD Function" it could be really hard because i should write the function 120 times and sometimes hte column names could be change so always i have to check the code one by one because of that.

Is there a simple macro which replaces this characters in all columns .

Comment: how many rows in your 
table?

Comment: almost 100K but sometimes it could be more than a million rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**

*In retrospect, this is an overly complicated solution... The `translate()` function should be used, as pointed by another user. It could be integrated in a SAS function defined with `PROC FCMP` when used repeatedly.*

---

A combination of regular expressions and a DO loop can achieve that.

**Step 1: Build a conversion table in the following manner**

*Accentuated letters that resolve to the same replacement character are put on a single line, separated by the | symbol.*

```
data conversions;
  infile datalines dsd;
  input orig $ repl $;
  datalines;
ç,c
ğ,g
ı,l
ö|ò|ó,o
ë|è,e
;
```

**Step 2: Store original and replacement strings in macro variables**

```
proc sql noprint;
  select orig, repl, count(*)
    into :orig separated by ";",
         :repl separated by ";",
         :nrepl
    from conversions;
quit;
```

**Step 3: Do the actual conversion**

*Just to show how it works, let's deal with just one column.*

```
data convert(drop=i re);
  myString = "ç ğı òö ë, è";
  do i = 1 to &nrepl;
    re = prxparse("s/" || scan("&orig",i,";") || "/" || scan("&repl",i,";") || "/");
    myString = prxchange(re,-1,myString);
  end;
run;
```

Resulting `myString`: "c gl oo e, e"

**To process all character columns, we use an array**

Say your table is named `mySource` and you want all character variables to be processed; we'll create a vector called `cols` for that.

```
data convert(drop=i re);
  set mySource;
  array cols(*) _character_;
  do c = 1 to dim(cols);
    do i = 1 to &nrepl;
      re = prxparse("s/" || scan("&orig",i,";") || "/" || scan("&repl",i,";") || "/");
      cols(c) = prxchange(re,-1,cols(c));
    end;
  end;
run;
```

Answer (score 3):

When changing single characters TRANSLATE is the proper function, it will be one line of code.

```
translated = translate(string,"cgio","çğıö");
```

Answer (score 2):

First get all your columns from dictionary, and then replace the values of all of them in a macro do loop.

You can try a program like this (Replace MYTABLE with your table name):

```
proc sql; 
select name , count(*) into :columns separated by ' ', :count
from dictionary.columns 
where memname = 'MYTABLE'; 
quit; 

%macro m;
data mytable;
set mytable;
%do i=1 %to &count;
%scan(&columns ,&i) = tranwrd(%scan(&columns ,&i),"ç","c");
%scan(&columns ,&i) = tranwrd(%scan(&columns ,&i),"ğ","g");
...
%end;

%mend;

%m;
```

Comment: i haven't tried yet but i will. I'm going to give a feedback